# Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you enabled the php_fileinfo extension?). Laeavel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

my db create user.php

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('avatar')->nullable();

        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

My user.php

```
   protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password','avatar',
];
```

my web.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Route::post('/upload',[UserController::class,'uploadavatar']);

Comment: you have not posted the code that is causing the issue rather posted all other codes. btw as the error says, your fileinfo extension is not enabled in your php.ini file.

Comment: can you tell me what code is causing trouble?

Comment: you are validating form right??

Comment: yess im validating a form

Comment: the error is coming from that validation part. your fileinfo extentension is not enabled.

Comment: Can you tell me which extension?

Comment: it's on your error. `php_fileinfo` this extension is not enabled in your php installation.